# Running brew doctor shows I have 3 different python "config" scripts installed. How do I get rid of them so that I no longer receive this warning?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, python

I have been told that there is a default Python installed on OSX, and that deleting it will cause SEVERE system issues, however, I want to clear these warnings in brew doctor.

This is what the message says:

```
    Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

How do I clear them and what happens if I just delete all three of those config scripts?

Comment: You have installed python 2.7 by a method that is not  Apple's or Homebrew. How was it installed?

Comment: I do not remember ever installing python manually. Are you suggesting that these python files found in /usr/local/bin/ can be deleted? Where would I find the default OSX Python installation so I can be sure never to delete that one?

Comment: Apple's python is in /usr/bin/python  - /usr/local/bin is for other installs and Homebrew

Answer (score 3):

Those scripts refer to an official Apple installation of Python. You can uninstall those safely this way:

1. Open "Applications" in Mac Finder and drag Python to the trash bin.
2. Empty the trash bin

Note:

- the MacOS system Python is `/usr/bin/python`
- Homebrew Python(s) will be located in `/usr/local/bin/`
- Pythons installed as an Apple application live in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`

Comment: Doing this did not clear the brew doctor errors for me.